# How to correctly store spare Cell Phone Battery?

Tags: batteries, cellphone, storage

I've got a spare battery for my cell phone. I'm wondering what the correct way to store it would be, so as to maximize the battery time. Should I recharge the battery to 100%, then leave it aside, or should I use about 20-30% of the battery before putting it aside?

Comment: Assuming a LiPo battery?

Comment: @Thomas If you mean li-polymeter then yes, it says that on the back of the battery.

Comment: Actually the primary battery is li-polymeter, the spare one that this question is about, says Li-ion.

Comment: Nice name and picture @Click!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Battery University [page](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) recommends you store them at 40% charge.

Comment: Time to go drain some batteries!

Comment: that would be a little too low because I'd need to pick up this battery and plug it in whenever the primary dies out and I'm away from a power source. What would you recommend for that?

Comment: @Click Upvote, it applies to Li-ion and Li-po batteries. It would seem it is not possible to store a battery at full charge for any long period of time.

Comment: @clickUpvote, it would hold about 40% charge for months, you should freeze them.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this would be impacted by how often you swap the batteries, i.e. how long do you store them?

If you use a battery until it is dead, then put in the fresh one, while the now-used one is put in a charger, then I would not consider this *storage* at all, but merely normal use.

If you usually use just the one battery, and have a second for emergencies, then @Thomas answer makes more sense.

Comment: Its the first (i.e I use one till its dead, then put the other in), but I only need to do this once every day or such.